# How to restrict double click on button in struts /Java?

Tags: java, struts2

I have created a web form. On Click of button, database query would be fired. The Problem is that when user clicks on button twice, query would be fired 2 times. I want to prevent that. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/token.html)

`Struts2` has a built in mechanism for stopping double form submission that works on the server side instead of the client. You may need to add the `TokenInterceptor` if its not on the defaultStack you're using.

[Here](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/tags/token_tag.html) is a quick tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use jQuery you could consider using

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

onclick or onsubmit call `$.blockUI();`

Some Demos for your reference

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this case, if javascript is not enabled in the browser then it won't work.

Comment: Does your application work if javascript is enabled ? Now-a-days most of the web applications depend on javascript. If you think users would disable javascript, then this task might have to be done in action classes or using s:token tag as suggested by Liviu T.

Answer (score 0):

The belt and braces approach is to set a JavaScript flag variable when the button is clicked and block subsequent submits "onclick". Then, on the server, implement the "synchronizer token pattern" (you can just Google that term to find out about it).